# Haskell, pulling both lists from a tuple of lists

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'm making a "merge sort" using 2 helper functions.  The first helper function splits the lists into a tuple of lists putting odd and even indexes in the separate lists.

```
Example: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Returns: ([1,3,5],[2,4,6])
```

The second helper function assumes that the lists are sorted and merges them.

I'm to implement a merge sort of an unsorted list using these 2 functions.

I have this terribly inefficient piece that essentially splits (length - 1) * 2 times and merges the list (length - 1) times.

```
   sort length (z:zs)
        | length == 0 = (z:zs)
        | otherwise   = sort (length - 1) (merge (fst (split(z:zs))) (snd (split(z:zs)))
```

I'm calling split twice to get the same info that was done on the first split, and I'm not recursing far enough (where each list is just a singleton and then merge them all).

How can I recurse to the singleton case and pull out both elements of the tuple at the same time?

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Take a look at `where` or `let` constructions. Use something like `where (first, second) = split ...`. Also, you can use construction like this `all@(x:xs)` to bind a variable to entire list.

Comment: What does the `length` parameter achieve?

Comment: If you have a different question post it as a new question, and don't just add it to your existing question.

Comment: Oh! Thanks that makes sense. And sorry, I'm new to stack overflow.  I will remember that for the future.

Comment: do you really need your length parameter or you can detect the singleton case in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`uncurry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) to convert `merge` to an un-curried function and pass `split(z:zs)` as argument:

```
sort (length - 1) $ uncurry merge $ split (z:zs)
```

The `uncurry` function transforms function of type `a -> b -> c` into functions of type `(a, b) -> c`. In your case `merge` has type `[a] -> [a] -> [a]` while `uncurry merge` has type `([a], [a]) -> [a]` and `([a], [a])` is the return type of `split`.

Alternatively you can simply use a `let` or a `where` clause to refer to the result of `split`:

```
let (left, right) = split (z:zs)
in sort (length - 1) $ merge left right
```

which is an improved version of:

```
let res = split (z:zs)
in sort (length - 1) $ merge (fst res) (snd res)
```

---

As a side note your `sort` function is incorrect. Your definition is like:

```
sort length (z:zs) = ...
```

however this matches only *non-empty* lists. It's also pretty useless to consider the case `length == 0` when it can never occurr.

Your definition of `sort` outght to consider the empty case too:

```
sort _ [] = []
sort length (z:zs) = ...
```

Comment: I hope one day that all makes sense to me!  For now, thank you kindly!

Comment: What is behavior of `uncurry` when it is applied to a function of arity greater than two?

Comment: @Mark the standard reply to that is that in Haskell every function is of arity exactly 1 (one). So `c` in `a->b->c ===> (a,b)->c` can also be `d->e->f->...` just the same.

Comment: @WillNess, yes I know, but I'm still new to Haskell, I already tested it: `uncurry f $ (1, 2) 3` - it works :-)

Comment: @Mark it is perfectly OK to ask. :)